# How to debug audio file not playing? EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'play' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic2

I want to load a audio file from a json. 
I get an error:

E/Web Console( 1154): EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'play' of undefined at file:///android_asset/www/build/main.js:5

I am running latest Ionic2/Angular2

What can I do?

Thanks!
Fred

My home.ts script:

```
loadSessionID() {
    //load the new sessionID from JSON
      this.sessionService.load()
        .then(
          session => {
            this.session = session.results.slice(this.currentSessionId-1,this.currentSessionId); //     array index item first position = 0
            console.log('Load session with id: '+this.currentSessionId);
            this.playSessionID();
          },
          error => console.error('Error loading session ID'+error)
        );
    }

  playSessionID(){
    // Create a MediaPlugin instance.  Expects path to file or url as argument
    var mp3URL = this.mediaURLPrefix+this.session.filename;

    var file = new MediaPlugin(mp3URL);

    // Catch the Success & Error Output
    // Platform Quirks
    // iOS calls success on completion of playback only
    // Android calls success on completion of playback AND on release()
    file.init
      .then(
        ()    => console.log('Playback finished'), 
        (err) => console.log('Somthing went wrong! error code: ' + err.code + ' message: ' + err.message)
      );

    //play audio file
    file.play();
  }
```

Comment: What is line 5 of main.js? What is `MediaPlugin`?

Comment: Hi @MattWay , thanks for your questions. No idea what is on line 5 of main.js. It is an android APK build. How can I peek in such a package? This MediaPlugin: http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/mediaplugin/

Comment: I found main.js, line 5 says `typeof self !== "undefined" ? self :`